# Java to Mongo Document date

Tags: java, mongodb, date, mongodb-query

I am inserting a document by converting the pojo to document object using static parse method from Mongo driver.

```
Document newList = parse(gson.toJson(myPoJo));
collections.insertOne(newList);
```

This pojo has a Date attribute. But parse method will not adhere this type and convert it to string i think. So after insert my document is something like below.

```
 { "auditInfo" : {
        "updatedDate" : "Feb 28, 2000 3:39:20 PM",
   } 
}
```

Problem with this is i wont be able to perform date comparison in mongo query.

Please advise on how to handle this.

Comment: Can you add the java code pls ?

Comment: added java code

Comment: Where do you see that output ? Do you use any viewer ?

Comment: For viewing mongo documents i use RoboMongo

Comment: My expectation is to insert the date and in another query i should be able to compare this date

Comment: Viewer  will show the date in user time zone and locale. Can you check the type in Robomongo ? Better if you can check in mongo shell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136850/discussion-between-geek-and-veeram).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like below.

Using Mongo Java Driver:

```
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
 MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
 MongoCollection col = db.getCollection("input");

 Input input = new Input();
 input.setName("name");
 input.setDate(new Date());

 Document doc = new Document();
 doc.append("name", input.getName());
 doc.append("date", input.getDate())

 col.insertOne(doc);
```

Using Morphia

Morphia takes care of validating & mapping mongo data to and from request and response.

Pojo:

```
package org.mongodb.morphia;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity("input")
public class Input implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private String name;

    private Date date;
}
```

Main:

```
public class MorphiaClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
    morphia.mapPackage("org.mongodb.morphia");
    final Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient(), "test");
    Input input = new Input();
    input.setName("name");
    input.setDate(new Date());
    datastore.save(input);
}
```

Comment: how good is morphia for abstract classes and inherited concrete classes?

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in the [java driver documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/bson/documents/#document), the driver accepts a variety of commonly used java types and converts these into the corresponding BSON types internally. You must pass objects of these supported types for this to work though.

The value of your field `updatedDate` must be of type `java.util.Date`. The java driver will then be able to convert it to the correct type, [`org.bson.BsonDateTime`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/bson/src/main/org/bson/BsonDateTime.java), afterwards.

Comment: My Java object has `updatedDate` of type `java.util.Date` type. But i believe i am converting it into json and then converting into Mongo document. Looks like this is causing the problem

Comment: Geek, did you find any solution for it?